# How can I make a flex item's height expand with the content and stop it from overflowing?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I make a flex item's height expand with the content and stop it from overflowing?

This is the JSX:

```
<div className="app-elements">
    <main>
        <Alert />
        <Routes />
    </main>
    <Footer />
</div>
```

And this is the css:

```
.app-elements {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 12vh;
}

main {
  width: 78%;
  padding: 0.45em;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-height: 88vh;
}
```

My main element wont grow when the content height is higher than its height and it overflows how can I fix this?

Comment: min-height:100% instead of height:100% ?

Answer (score 0):

The `main` should have this css:

```
main {
   width: 78%;
   padding: 0.45em;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

You can read more about flex-grow here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow